# ofstream.put not working properly

Tags: c++

I'm working on a school-assignment and running into trouble in the very end.
So the idea behind the program is to decypher a txt file, however when trying to print to a different textfile it simply doesn't print, even though it's using the exact same code as other functions that are able to print.

Here's the code: 
(not all of it is relevant, as it includes code for smaller assignments as well)
(also, some of the comments are in dutch, sorry!)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


string output;
string input;

char rotate(char a, int r, bool e)
{
    //precondition:
    assert(r>=0);
    //postcondition: we hebben a ge-encrypt of ge-decrypt
    int b;
    if (a<32)
    {
        b=a;
        return b;
    }
    if (32<=a<=128)
    {
        if (e)
        {
            b = (a-32 + (r% (128-32))+(128-32))%(128-32)+32;
            return b;
        }
        else
        {
            b = (a-32 - (r% (128-32))+(128-32))%(128-32)+32;
            return b;
        }
    }

}

void test_rotate()
{
    //precondition
    assert(true);
    //postcondition: we printen het origineel, de ge-encrypte versie, en de inverse van de ge-encrypte versie
    cout << "Wat is de character die je wilt encrypten \n";
    char a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "\nVoer een willekeurig natuurlijk getal in\n";
    int r;
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> r;
        cout << a << " " << rotate(a, r, true) << " " << rotate(rotate(a, r, true), r, false) << endl;
    }
}

bool open_input_and_output_file (ifstream& in_stream, ofstream& out_stream)
{
    //precondition:
    assert(true);
    //postcondition: vraag de namen van de files, open ze en geef aan of dat is gelukt of niet.
    string in_file_name;
    string out_file_name;
    cout << "geef de naam die van het te encrypten/decrypten bestand\n";
    cin >> in_file_name;
    cout << "geef de naam van het bestand waarnaar de encryptie/decryptie geschreven moet worden\n";
    cin >> out_file_name;

    in_stream.open(in_file_name.c_str());
    out_stream.open(out_file_name.c_str());
    if (in_stream.fail() || out_stream.fail() || (in_file_name==out_file_name))
    {
        cout << "de bestanden kunnen niet geopend worden of zijn hetzelfde bestand";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


void OTP(ifstream& in_stream, ofstream& out_stream)
{
    //precondition:
    assert(true);
    /*postcondition:
    Vraag of ge-encrypt of gedecrypt moet worden,
    open de files waarvoor dit moet gebeuren,
    vraag voor de sleutel,
    encrypt/decrypt de file.
    */
    cout << "Wilt u 0: decrypten of 1: encrypten?\n";
    bool crypten;
    cin >> crypten;
    open_input_and_output_file(in_stream, out_stream);
    cout << "Geef de sleutel voor het encrypten/decrypten\n";
    unsigned int key;
    cin >> key;
    char character;
    srand(key);
    in_stream.get(character);
    while(in_stream)
    {
        out_stream.put (rotate (character, rand(),crypten));
        in_stream.get(character);
        cout << "lolnope";
    }
}

void OTP_secret(ifstream& in_stream, ofstream& out_stream, int key)
{
    srand(key);
    char character;
    in_stream.get(character);
    int count=1;
    out_stream.open("source.txt");
    while(count <= 5 && in_stream)
    {
        out_stream.put (rotate(character, rand(), false));
        in_stream.get(character);
        count++;
    }
}

bool check_key(ifstream& in_stream, ofstream& out_stream)
{
    char character;
    in_stream.get(character);
    int count = 1;
    while (count <= 5 && in_stream)
    {
        if ((character <= 'z') && (character >= 'A') /*|| (character == ' ')*/)
        {
            in_stream.get(character);
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int find_key(ifstream& in_stream, ofstream& out_stream)
{
    int count = 0;
    OTP_secret(in_stream,out_stream,0);
    while (!check_key(in_stream, out_stream))
    {
        OTP_secret(in_stream, out_stream, count);
        count++;
    }
    count--;
    return count;
}

void secret(ifstream& in_stream, ofstream& out_stream)
{

    in_stream.open("secret.txt");
    int key = find_key(in_stream, out_stream);
    char character;
    srand(key);
    in_stream.get(character);
    /*while(in_stream)
    {
        out_stream.put (rotate(character, rand(), false));
        cout << rotate(character,rand(),false);
        in_stream.get (character);
    }*/
    while(in_stream)
    {
        out_stream.put (rotate (character, rand(), false));
        cout << rotate (character, rand(), false);
        in_stream.get(character);
    }
    if (out_stream.is_open())
        cout << "\nout_stream is open\n";
    if (in_stream.is_open())
        cout << "in_stream is open\n";
}

int main()
{
    ifstream in_stream;
    ofstream out_stream;
    //test_rotate();
    //open_input_and_output_file(inputfile,outputfile);
    //OTP(in_stream,out_stream);
    secret(in_stream, out_stream);

    return 0;
}
```

The issue lies within the void secret, in the final while(in_stream).
out_stream.put isn't writing to the output file, while cout printing the exact same thing will write.
I've thrown some extra checks in there to see if the files are open etc.

I'm completely clueless as to where the issue is, as using the exact same code in the void OTP_secret does work, as well as in void OTP.

Comment: Did you check for an error when you closed the file?  Did you check for an error when you opened it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `out_stream.open(...);` in your `secret` function, i.e. you never open the output stream.

Comment: it is opened in otp_secret, there is a check in secret to see if it is opened and it returns that it is, so that isn't the issue. I tried adding another out_stream.open in secret and that didnt fix it.